# How to escape "@" in properties file spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a spring boot app that connects to salesforce to fetch data from salesforce and push the data into SQL server DB.
Am trying to fetch all the properties from application.properties file.
My password has @ and hence while reading that property during execution I get "example" as my password instead of "example@country"

```
Eg : 
Pwd = example@country
```

I checked some useful links but no luck, any help is appreciated

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html

Utility package for fetching config props.

```
                package SFToJava.Utils;

                import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
                import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
                import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
                @Configuration
                public class configUtility {
                    @Autowired
                    private Environment env;

                    public String getProperty(String pPropertyKey) {
                        return env.getProperty(pPropertyKey);
                    }
                }
```

properties file :

```
password = example@country
```

I fetch the data in my service class as follows:

```
            loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id",configUtil.getProperty("consumerKey")));
            loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", configUtil.getProperty("consumerSecret")));
            loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", configUtil.getProperty("username")));
            loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", configUtil.getProperty("password")));
```

I expect the password should have "example@country" while parsed to the list instead of getting "example" only.

fyi. am able to connect to Salesforce by directly using the password like below

```
            private static final String username = "******";
            private static final String password = "example@coutnry";
            private static final String consumerKey = "*************8";
            private static final String consumerSecret = "************";

loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", consumerKey));
        loginParams.add(new 
BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", consumerSecret));
        loginParams.add(new 
BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
        loginParams.add(new 
BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        loginParams.add(new 
BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
```

Comment: have you tried `\@` or \\@ ?

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using? I do not have to escape `@` character. It works for `@` and `\@`. Tested with spring boot 2.1.4.

Comment: Am using 2.1.6 , i tried both \@ and \\@ and am simply gettiing error stating :
Multiple markers at this line
- missing LineBreak at '@'
- missing LineBreak at '\'
- 'username' is an unknown property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do not have to escape `@` or you can use the escaped `\\@` in your `.properties` file:

```
mail.address=user\\@domain.com
```

But I had some issues using this for authentication purposes. In that case you might want to use the encoded `%40` for `@`:

```
# replace @ in email with %40
mail.address=user%40domain.com
```